# Windows service install on different machine

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, service

I have created windows service in Visual studio 2010 in  c#.net  framework 3.5 . My operating system is windows 8 64 Bit.

This service working correctly  as expected on my local machine.

but now I want to install it on different machine having operating systems Server 2003 (SP2), windows 7, windows vista etc.

My service setup executable  file is created at  solution folder  location ....bin\obj\x86\Debug\Service.exe. and on one more location ..\obj\x86\Debug\Service.exe. let me know whic one to use.

I have install it locally with installutil command and it worked.   Please let me know how to install this Service.exe on other machine

But when I copied  Service.exe on other machine  and run installutil command then it gives me error on command prompt as 
 "System.BadImageException: Could not load file or assembly "XXXXXX.exe" or one of its dependencies.This assembly is builtup by runtime newer  than currently loaded runtime and cannot  be loaded."

I have set target platform to v2.0 and target client  to "Any CPU".

Please let me  know to  do it.

Comment: You should not be distributing a debug version. Build a release version. Also, if your target machines might be 32-bit instead of 64, make sure you set the Target CPU to x86. (And we don't do "URGENT" requests here - all questions are equally important, and you're getting free help. Telling us we have to do it "URGENTLY" is rather rude - you're asking for a donation of our time to solve *your problem* and then telling us to rush to do so. If you need "URGENT" help, pay someone to provide you with their undivided attention to your problem.)

Comment: Thanks Ken for the reply. I apologize if   requesting solution urgent is being rude. My intention was not to hurt anybody or being rude.